# PHP code doesn't work in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with a php code in wordpress.

I have a booking website and I need to add a Booking Fee when a stay is going to be payed by the guest (on the checkout page). I'm using WP Rentals theme in wordpress and woocommerce for the payments.
To do this I found the following instructions: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/, so I used the code bellow and Code Snippets to implement the change but nothing happens. No extra fee is included and no error is showed.

```
/**
 * Add a standard $ value surcharge to all transactions in cart / checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_surcharge' ); 
function wc_add_surcharge() { 
global $woocommerce; 

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
return;

$county = array('US');
// change the $fee to set the surcharge to a value to suit
$fee = 1.00;

if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) : 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $fee, true, 'standard' );  
endif;
}
```

I'm quite begginer in this world so I don't know where is the mistake.

Many thanks!

Comment: My guess is that by the time Code Snippets loads your php, it's too late for the `add_action` hooks. I would suggest creating a simple plugin for this instead.

Comment: Try removing the condition checks and if any changes

Comment: @disinfor, so do you think that the steps that I followed are correct and that it is a time problem?